# Building a standardized exception/error message collection

Tags: c#, winforms

We are building a very large project with WinForms, C#. For exception/error messages every developer writes what comes to their mind at that moment. This makes hard or slows down tracking down errors.

I was wondering what is a good way of building a project wide error/exception library with error codes for each exception so that everyone uses the same messages in similar situations?

Comment: Winforms, for a new, very large project?  It is rather hard to apply modern architecture principles (MVVM / MVC) to WinForms (though it can be done).

Comment: Yes unfortunately it's winforms :(

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Enterprise Library might be what you are looking for, as it has a block for exception handling. This lets you define consistent exception behavior per layer of your application.

Quick overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698(v=pandp.50).aspx

Basically you need to put all your exception related stuff into a config file. There is some non-trivial setup to get this going. Here is a short(ish) guide, although there are many more out there:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10255/Exception-Handling-Logging-Application-Block-Enter

Comment: I personally did not like Enterprise Library when I used it some time ago (the complexity of the setup being one factor).

Comment: Config can be a beast, I agree. An alternative might be using the AOP component of the spring.net framework: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-aspect-library.html#exception-aspect